# How to get all data in Yii As Json output in a parameter

Tags: php, json, yii

I'm trying to get all datas in `Yii` as json format and i've already read everything about this specially this one:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/612/simple-web-apis-for-your-yii-app/
as you can see, download not working

i need to get something like WordPress api for all datas automatically:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

or this example:
http://iseetv.biz/api/

it's get all datas as json in `wordpress/api` address.and i need this one like wordpress api.But, what are the all datas? how can i get those datas as json completly?

**for example this is my controller:**

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Declares class-based actions.
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
            // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
            // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
            'page'=>array(
                'class'=>'CViewAction',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
     * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * This is the action to handle external exceptions.
     */
    public function actionError()
    {
        if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
        {
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                echo $error['message'];
            else
                $this->render('error', $error);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the contact page
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
                $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
                $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                    "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

                mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
                $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model=new LoginForm;

        // if it is ajax validation request
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if($model->validate() && $model->login())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        $arr = array('controller'=>$this->id, 'action'=>$this->action->id,'status' =>'OK');
        Yii::app()->user->logout();
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
    }


}
```

How to do that?

Comment: what's exactly do you want to do & what problem are you facing ?

Comment: i need an automatically api for all datas like wordpress api: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ but i can't fiqured out what are the datas ?

Answer (score 0):

In your function you want to return JSON-like API data, you should have something like this

```
public function actionSomeAPI()
{
    $data = GetDataFrom::model()->findAll();

    //... parse the data to reduce it to what you want

    // encode the data as JSON and send it to
    // the client
    echo CJavaScript::jsonEncode($data);

    // since we don't want to render the view,
    // and we already have the data we want sent
    // to the browser, we have to halt Yii here.
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```